# Same openGL calls yield different results in LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl

We're supposed to use LWJGL 2.9.3 to create a simple application that displays a wireframe object. I created a test class based off of the first example code from http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter01.html What I end up with is a program that flashes a white square for a brief moment and then disappears. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the test code:

```
package Test.LWJGL;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

import static CS355.LWJGL.LWJGLSandbox.DISPLAY_HEIGHT;
import static CS355.LWJGL.LWJGLSandbox.DISPLAY_WIDTH;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glFlush;


public class LWJGLTest {
    public static void render() {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glOrtho(0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
            glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(0.75f, 0.25f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.75f, 0.0f);
        glEnd();
        glFlush();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(DISPLAY_WIDTH,DISPLAY_HEIGHT));
            Display.setFullscreen(false);
            Display.create();

            glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);

            while(!Display.isCloseRequested() && !Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
                if(Display.isVisible()) {
                    render();
                }
                else {
                    if(Display.isDirty()) {
                        render();
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException ex) {}
                }
                Display.update();
                Display.sync(60);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            Mouse.destroy();
            Keyboard.destroy();
            Display.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL is a state machine. This means, there are lots of states which you can set, and which will influence the final rendering result in some well-defined way. These states are  *never* automatically reset, they just stay as you set them, until you change them. There are no such things as "frames" or "scene objects", just a stream of state-setting or drawing commands.

OpenGL's matrix stack is also just a state. The function `glOrtho` will *multiply* the current top element of the currently selected matrix stack with that ortho matrix, and will replace the top element by that result.

Assume the Ortho matrix is called `O`. Initially, all of GL's matrices will be identiy. So when you call `render` for the first time, you'll get: `M = M * O = I * O = O`. However, the second time, you will get `M = M * O = O * O`. And so on.

You have to explicitely reset your matrix back to identity at the beginning of the frame:

```
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(...);
```

You should be aware that the code you are using is not very good. It uses the `MODELVIEW` stack for projection matrices, which is meant to go to `GL_PROJECTION`. But before you try to learn about that staff, be warned that all of that is completely deprecated in the GL since a decade. Modern core versions of OpenGL do not support these functions at all.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a better resource than http://www.glprogramming.com for modern openGL and if lwjgl 2.9.3 supports more up-to-date functionality?

Comment: For modern GL, [open.gl](http://open.gl) and [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](http://alfonse.bitbucket.org/oldtut/) are quite good. lwjgl should support modern GL, but I'm not familiar with it.